# How to configure symfony2 for X-Frame-Options?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

how can i stop clickjacking in my symfony2 application?

After research i found that i should add below line in .htaccess file

Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"

but after adding in .htaccess file,  i am getting "Internal Server Error"

**FYI**

I added x-frame option line like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
    Header append x-frame-options "DENY"
</IfModule>
```

Is there any other option to apply X-frame-options in symfony2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like youre have no right to modify header in apache.
If you want to do it in Symfony you should create a ResponseListener and add headers to each response. Here is an example:

**ResponseListener.php:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {   
        $event->getResponse()->headers->set('x-frame-options', 'deny');
    }   
}
```

**services.yml**

```
kernel.listener.response_listener:
    class: MyCorp\MyBundle\Listener\ResponseListener
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Klipach for your help,

And I am writing one more alternative to enable X-frame-options

In .htaccess file add below line

```
Header append x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"
```

And if you get internal server error. It means **headers** module is disabled
so use below command to enable

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 restart
```